# C# uwp record two webcams at 60 frames per second

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

What I need to do is record 2 usb webcams at 60 fps 1280x720 format in UWP c#.
The camera's are currently previewed in a **CaptureElement**

This is how it start previewing:

```
    public async Task StartPreviewSideAsync(DeviceInformation deviceInformation)
    {
        if (deviceInformation != null)
        {
            var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings {VideoDeviceId = deviceInformation.Id};
            try
            {
                _mediaCaptureSide = new MediaCapture();

                var profiles = MediaCapture.FindAllVideoProfiles(deviceInformation.Id);

                Debug.WriteLine(MediaCapture.IsVideoProfileSupported(deviceInformation.Id) + " count: " + profiles.Count);

                var match = (from profile in profiles
                    from desc in profile.SupportedRecordMediaDescription
                    where desc.Width == 1280 && desc.Height == 720 && Math.Abs(Math.Round(desc.FrameRate) - 60) < 1
                    select new {profile, desc}).FirstOrDefault();

                if (match != null)
                {
                    settings.VideoProfile = match.profile;
                    settings.RecordMediaDescription = match.desc;
                }

                await _mediaCaptureSide.InitializeAsync(settings);
                SideCam.Source = _mediaCaptureSide;
                await _mediaCaptureSide.StartPreviewAsync();

                _displayRequestSide = new DisplayRequest();
                _displayRequestSide.RequestActive();

                DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Landscape;

                CameraManager.GetCameraManager.CurrentSideCamera = deviceInformation;
                IsPreviewingSide = true;
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("The app was denied access to the camera");
                IsPreviewingSide = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("MediaCapture initialization failed. {0}", ex.Message);
                IsPreviewingSide = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the method that starts the recording:

```
    public IAsyncOperation<LowLagMediaRecording> RecBackCam(StorageFile fileBack)
    {
        var mp4File = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.HD720p);
        if (mp4File.Video != null)
            mp4File.Video.Bitrate = 3000000;

        return _mediaCaptureBack.PrepareLowLagRecordToStorageFileAsync(mp4File, fileBack);
    }
```

but it does not record 60fps because it cannot find a profile for it (in the preview method).
and when I use this (in the recoding method):

```
mp4File.Video.FrameRate.Numerator = 3600;
mp4File.Video.FrameRate.Denominator = 60;
```

it records 60 frames per second but frame 1 and 2 are the same 3 and 4 and so on. But I need actual 60 frames per second.
all the basics of the code comes from the mdsn website
[link to code on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/basic-photo-video-and-audio-capture-with-mediacapture#capture-a-video).

Comment: What is the camera model? Does it even allow 60 FPS recording? :-)

Comment: yes it is a ELP camera and it supports 60 fps 1280x720

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the frame rate for [MediaCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241124), we can use [VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700895.aspx) method like the following:

```
 await _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoRecord, encodingProperties);
```

For the `encodingProperties`, we can get it from [VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br211994) method, this method returns a list of the supported encoding properties for the video device. If your camera supports 60 fps, 1280x720 resolution then you should be able to find the corresponding [VideoEncodingProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh701217) in this list.

For more info, please see the article [Set format, resolution, and frame rate for MediaCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/set-media-encoding-properties) and also [Camera resolution sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraResolution) on GitHub.